# Why was my question titled "native English inferiority" closed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88385/native-english-inferiority) was "closed as not a real question."  Obviously it's a real question, and I would disbelieve anyone's explicit assertion (as opposed to this rude sarcastic boilerplate notice) that it appeared not to be a real question.

Can someone explain the real reason for the closing?

Comment: You're right! It's not NARQ, it's off topic: peeving disguised as a question.

Comment: I would vote to reopen it, but I think the question needs to be adapted to the answer provided. Your premise (and the bulk of your question), while intuitive to a degree, remains anecdotal. You're also drawing distinctions between *native* and *foreign* words, when technically all the words you describe would be considered *native*. I think you're trying to describe something (pretension based on word origin) which may have many counterexamples. The *lexical strata* of English may not have the *social significance* that you ascribe to it. In that sense, alcas doesn't answer your base question.

Comment: I can't explain other peoples' votes, but I would have voted to close General Reference. I answered your question in comments.

Comment: Your question rambles, so it is difficult to pick out what exactly is being requested. On re-reading, it seems like all you want is a word (or phrase) to describe a subset of vocabulary that was imported from another language, seems native now, but still is considered 'higher class'? If so, MetaED gave the best answer, 'prestige' vocabulary.

Comment: @Mitch : I wasn't asking for the name for a "subset of vocabulary".  I was asking about the process by which words brought by foreign conquerors come to be perceived differently from other words.

Comment: @Matt Эллен : I was not "peeving" and I was not disguising anything.  My question was a question seeking an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Oh OK. Maybe we're just all covering because we dont know the right term for it. I think you might be more successful over at linguistics.SE.

Comment: @Mitch: I definitely think you've got a point there. If it *were* to be the case that there was a (reasonably) well-established term for OP's phenomenon, I've no doubt someone would have posted it as an answer. It would probably have collected many upvotes by now, and the question would never have been closed at all.

Answer (score 7):

I think your question has a lot of potential, and if you give some time to editing it, I think it has a good chance of being re-opened.  Here are my thoughts about it, after my initial reading.

I would have closed this as "not constructive" before "not a real question." To start with, the crux of your question is

> Is there a name for this phenomenon, whereby...people feel that words that come from formerly more civilized foreigners are more civilized, literate, dignified, or formal than native words?

This premise is seriously flawed and opens the entire question up to discussion and debate. For instance, you make the assertion that

> "Substance" is more dignified than "stuff"; "decay" more formal than "rotting"; "predict" more scientific than "foretell."

but that's rather all your opinion, as is which former societies are more civilized, etc.  We could argue about it, but that is not really what you are asking about, and you're entitled to think what you think about how language makes you feel.

You also seem to make the assumption that most English speakers know their word origins.  I might feel that "substance" is more hoity-toity than "stuff," but that's got nothing to do with it being Latin or Greek or wherever it comes from, because I haven't the slightest idea about its origin.  They are two English words and one feels more precise and less colloquial to me than another.

As for the "not a real question" close reason, it *is* difficult to figure out what you are asking.  Your title is not very descriptive, and you lead with opinionated examples before you mention what you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: Despite my agreement in principle, I think that though most people, even well-educated ones, aren't conscious even vaguely of the etymology of most words, but they really do have a good grasp of prestige words (especially by the number of syllables and somewhat lower frequency). That is, the details of the assumptions may not be correct but the general direction still works.

Comment: I agree that people are not conscious of the etymologies, but nonetheless they feel differently about words with certain etymologies than the way they feel about words with other etymologies.  Thus my question does not presuppose that people _know_ the origins of words; rather it assumes that those origins _cause_ them to having certain feelings about them.

Answer (score 3):

NARQ seems a bit unreasonable to me - I voted to close as Too Localised.

I probably should have opted for Not Constructive. I don't believe there *is* an established term for the linguistic phenomenon being queried, so it seemed to me we'd just get a variety of more-or-less "snappy" coinages to be voted on in a "beauty contest".

The truth is I voted TL because if it turned out there *was* an established term, I figured I'd still have some chance of justifying my closevote.

I'd also mention that the question itself was very long-winded and did look a lot like a peeve. I freely admit that coloured my judgement; if the same question had been posed in a sentence or two, I'd probably not have closevoted.

FWIW - if the "target expression" does exist, one might have expected it to have turned up in [Normans vs. Saxons: cow = beef, sheep = mutton, chicken =?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85638/normans-vs-saxons-cow-beef-sheep-mutton-chicken), for example. That's just one of many similar questions touching on the "status" of words adopted from more powerful and/or sophisticated invading cultures.

Comment: The "long-winded" aspect of it was simply a list of examples that appeared to be necessary to make it clear what the question was about.  The answer that was posted makes it clear that someone was capable of understanding the question and that it was indeed a question.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't mean to suggest the long-windedness made it hard to understand the *actual* question. You'll note that my comment got a few upvotes simply for parroting back the penultimate sentence, which imho was in and of itself a more than sufficient definition. Looking more closely now, I see Rory had already commented with the same point. I know we get a lot of questions here that don't give *enough* context, but I just feel you did yourself no favours by including *too much* ancillary detail. As implied above, if I were you I'd edit it down a bit to see if you can get it re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

I would have closed it as off-topic because it is more a linguistic question, than a question about English. In fact, the question is asking for a name of the described phenomenon (which is not limited to English) and in which other languages is such phenomenon present.

Closing it as not constructive doesn't seem correct to me, as the question is not asking the reason why words derived from Latin/Greek are preferred to other words of Germanic origin, but it is asking for a noun to use to describe the phenomenon.

I can understand why it has been closed as not a real question. Reading it, I had the feeling it was a broad question; only when I read the last sentence I was able to understand the question was about a specific word. Probably if the question's text had first the questions, and then the rest, the question would have been perceived differently from who read it.

Answer (score 1):

The question as posted has a few real and answerable  questions within it. On that basis I didn't vote to close after looking at the question, and moreover was surprised to see votes to close.

However, the text contains questionable, unnecessary, and irrelevant assertions that muddle the question.  I had and have no inclination to vote to reopen it or to write an answer for it.

The “ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical” part of the explanation for questions closed as not a real question seems properly applied; the question as posted *is* somewhat vague, overly broad, and rhetorical.  I suggest rewriting it for clarity and directness, leaving out less-relevant asides like mention of Clarke, Eriston and Etania.  Defending the question as it stands seems pointless.